# Sum of large numbers represented as arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

The numbers are stored in the arrays with their digits in reverse order. Here is a functions that should add two numbers, `a` and `b`, and store the sum in `result`:

```
public static void SumDigitArraysDifferentSize(int[] a, int[] b, int[] result)
{
      int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          int lhs = (i < a.Length) ? a[i] : 0;
          int rhs = (i < b.Length) ? b[i] : 0;

          result[i] = (result[i] + lhs + rhs) % 10;

          int carry = (result[i] + lhs + rhs) / 10;

          for (int j = 1; carry > 0; j++)
          {
              result[i + j] = (result[i + j] + carry) % 10;

              carry = (result[i + j] + carry) / 10;
          }
      }
}
```

However, if I add for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] lhs = { 9 }
    int[] rhs = { 9, 9 };

    int size = Math.Max(lhs.Length, rhs.Length) + 1;
    int[] result = new int[size];

    SumDigitArraysDifferentSize(lhs, rhs, result);

    PrintArray(result);   
}
```

the result is:

```
{ 8, 1, 1 }
```

instead of the expected:

```
{ 8, 0, 1 }
```

### What am I doing wrong?

---

For the MCVE:

```
public static void PrintArray(int[] Array)
{
    Console.Write("{");
    int length = Array.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(Array[i]);

        if (i < length - 1)
        {
             Console.Write(", ");
        }
    }
    Console.Write("}\n");
}
```

Comment: You're assigning to `result[i + j]` before checking for carry, that's one bug. You should first calculate the value to place into `result[i + j]`, then calculate carry, *then* place it into `result[i + j]`. Since I'm not sure this is the only bug I won't leave this as an answer.

Comment: Have you considered having `carry` as a simple variable that is carried between iterations, instead of having a separate loop that spreads the carry out into neighbouring values?

Comment: The line `int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);` can be changed to get the length of the array, as it is already the same value as the return from that line

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the remarks, yes at first, carry was a simple variable only in the outer loop.

Comment: Then why did you change it? The method becomes much simpler if you use it like that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You are probably right! Editing...

Comment: Don't change the question so that answers become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `result[i]`, and using the result again in the calculation of the `carry`.

This:

```
      result[i] = (result[i] + lhs + rhs) % 10;
      int carry = (result[i] + lhs + rhs) / 10;
```

Should be:

```
      var sum = result[i] + lhs + rhs;
      result[i] = (sum) % 10;
      int carry = (sum) / 10;
```

And the same for the calculation in the `for (int j = 1; ...)`.

Comment: Oh, the `result[i]` in the calculation of `carry` is the updated value after the first assignment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is the result of the proposed (by @Lasse V. Karlsen) implementation from the comment section

```
public static void SumDigitArrays(int[] a, int[] b, int[] result)
{
    int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int lhs = (i < a.Length) ? a[i] : 0;
        int rhs = (i < b.Length) ? b[i] : 0;

        int sum = result[i] + lhs + rhs;
        result[i] = sum % 10;

        int carry = sum / 10; 
        result[i + 1] = result[i + 1] + carry;
    }
}
```